# Are these two definitions of lattice equivalent?

Tags: lattice-orders

We know that $(L, \vee, \wedge)$ is called a lattice if $(L, \vee)$ is a join-semilattice and $(L, \wedge)$ is a meet-semilattice, i.e $(L, \vee)$ and $(L, \wedge)$ are idempotent commutative semigroups. However, the Wikipedia article gives another definition for lattice additionally: $(L, \vee, \wedge)$ is called a lattice if $(L, \vee)$ and $(L, \wedge)$ are commutative semigroups and the *absorption law* holds:
$$\forall a, b, c \in L:\;\; a \vee (a \wedge b) = a \;\;\;\;\;\;and\;\;\;\;\;\; a \wedge(a \vee b) = a$$
Now, the second definition implies the first one but is the converse true? I think it's not and actually the second definition is stronger.

Comment: See [wiki section on connection of two definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)#Connection_between_the_two_definitions).  Note that the first definition requires $L$ to be a poset to start off with (so meet and join respects this ordering), but the second definition $L$ is any set and the partial order is later obtained from the meet and join.

Comment: @user10354138 I have seen books (for example book by Roman) that don't require $L$ to be a partially ordered set and in fact the Wikipedia article on semilattice gives an algebraic definition for it besides the order-theoretic definition. Of course, the algebraic definition induces an order-theoretic lattice and the order-theoretic definition induces an algebraic lattice. Looks like what you're saying is we normally (but not always) use the first definition when $L$ is already a partially ordered set. Right?

Comment: @user10354138 I took a closer look at the books by Roman and Gratzer. The 'i.e' part is actually wrong. The algebraic structure should actually satisfy the absorption law as well. If it doesn't, then it's not called a lattice but the example given by Adayah is interesting for the sake of itself. Anyway, thank both of you.

Comment: @Adayah Please see my post above this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second definition does not follow from the first, as witnessed by the lattice $(\{0, 1\}, \max, \max)$.

Comment: That doesn't give you a meet semilattice that respects the ordering on $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: @user10354138 I don't know about meet semilattices, but the structures $(\{ 0, 1 \}, \wedge)$ and $(\{ 0, 1 \}, \vee)$ (where $\wedge = \vee = \max$) are idempotent commutative semigroups, which is the first condition from the question. Are you saying the "i.e." part of the question is wrong?

Comment: So it's indeed a counterexample.