# Finite distributive lattices and finite abelian monoids

Tags: combinatorics, representation-theory, boolean-algebra, lattice-orders

A structure of semilattice over T is the same thing than a structure of finite abelian monoid such that $\forall t \in T$, $t² = t$. 
Given a semilattice T, we get an abelian monoid by defining $a.b$ = $a \wedge b$ and conversely given an abelian monoid T such that $\forall t \in T$, $t² = t$, we get a semilattice by putting $a \leq b$ iff $a.b = a$ and we get that $a \wedge b = a.b$. 
I was wondering if we had a similar result for a finite distributive lattice T. I saw that if T is not just distributive but is a Boolean algebra, we get a correspondence with boolean rings. 
However, I found nothing about finite distributive lattice. Someone has an idea ? 
Thank you

Comment: Hi. Are you aware that lattices in general can be characterised [algebraically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)#As_algebraic_structure)? Under that correspondence, "finite distributive lattice" will end up corresponding to something like "finite commutative simple semiring whose addition and multiplication are both idempotent". Is that the type of thing you're looking for? See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4235946/, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4705680/, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4083334/, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring#Additively_idempotent_semirings

Comment: Thank you, in fact I hoped that we could obtain an easier description that the one you gave but It look likes that it is not the case.